# Bug Android serving local files net::ERR_FAILED

Tags: android, ionic-framework, webview, chromium, capacitor

As part of the development of our mobile app we are experiencing a local video playback issue in the Android WebView.

Technical stack:

- Ionic/Angular
- Capacitor (Native runtime acting as an interface between the webview and native code)
- Java Android

The problem occurs randomly when accessing a previously downloaded local video file.

Capacitor serves local files of the phone via a local server in order to bypass webview restrictions on the `file://` protocol. To do this it captures requests sent with the prefix `_capacitor_file` and returns a `WebResourceResponse` (Java Android) containing a `FileInputStream` however sometimes the response received by the webview is this:

```
GET http://localhost/_capacitor_file_/data/user/0/io.ionic.starter/files/videoXYZ.mp4 net::ERR_FAILED
```

There is no error that is emitted in Java that can clearly identify the source of the bug.

Source of Capacitor `WebViewLocalServer`: https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/blob/main/android/capacitor/src/main/java/com/getcapacitor/WebViewLocalServer.java

Another point that catches my eye is in the case where the video bugs, the returned request (just before it fails using Android Studio debugger) contains headers that seem wrong:

```
// Range seems wrong : 1055736-1055735 =\> video bug
{Accept-Ranges=bytes, Cache-Control=no-cache, Content-Range=bytes 1055736-1055735/1055736}
// Range is correct : 0-1589247 =\> video works
{Accept-Ranges=bytes, Cache-Control=no-cache, Content-Range=bytes 0-1589247/1589248}
```

I've opened an issue on the Capacitor repository : https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/6021 but I'm not sure it's at fault.

Instead, using the Android Studio Debugger, I think it may have to do with Chomium Webview because I see the response being send back to this function : https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/main/components/embedder_support/android/java/src/org/chromium/components/embedder_support/util/InputStreamUtil.java#L42 which is `@CalledByNative` this would explain why I don't see any Java errors...

This is way beyond my skills, that's why I need your help.

Basic app to reproduce the bug : https://github.com/brospars/bugvid

Comment: `the response received by the webview is this:

GET http://localhost/_capacitor_file_/data/user/0/io.ionic.starter/files/videoXYZ.mp4 net::ERR_FAILED` Received? Had a quick look at the github source code but i saw no "ERR FAILED". The webview will detect an error and then produce this message. But which error was on the server.. if there was one on the sever?

Comment: There is no "server" since it's a local video and no error in Java/js side

Comment: There is no server? `Capacitor serves local files of the phone via a local server ..`

Comment: A local server yes written in Java based on Chromium WebView request interceptor, I just wanted to be clear it's not a web server like Apache or else.

Comment: You better make clear where that ERR_FAILED comes from as talking about being a webserver yes or no brings you nowhere.

Comment: Sorry did not understand the question. The ERR_FAILED is coming from the chrome dev tools using chrome:://inspect/#devices. It works most of the time but it happens once in a while and the video stop or won't play at all.